# How to interpolate 2 different datasets (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, physics, analysis

I have 2 different datasets that I need to multiply with each other with the same number of bins (in Python).

One has a structure like this:

**Energy** (from E_min to E_max, in dE bins)

**Flux** (Depending on E_min and E_max, same number of bins as the energy)

The other one has a structure like this:

**Energy** (from E_min to E_max, in dE bins)

**Area** (dependent on energy, so same number of bins)

I would like to interpolate my area data to my flux data, so obtain the same number of points as my flux, so that I can multiply my flux by my area (Flux x Area [matched in energy bin])

I don't know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess first of all I would say to use `pandas` if you're not doing so already, and then it seems like all you need is a simple merge:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Energy':[1,2,3], 'Flux': [4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Energy':[1,2,3], 'Area': [10,11,12]})

df3 = df1.merge(df2,on='Energy',how='left')
df3['Flux_x_Area'] = df3['Flux'] * df3['Area']

#   Energy  Flux    Area    Flux_x_Area
#0    1      4       10         40
#1    2      5       11         55
#2    3      6       12         72
```

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, if you can provide a simple example of your exact problem (e.g. picture, table etc.) and what your expected outcome would be that would be a great help :)